# WordPress multisite gets error 500 with get_blog_details() or switch_to_blog() ... Sometimes

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, multisite

I have a WordPress multisite running fine with version 6.0.3 with a heavy custom theme that someone else has developed. I also have a dev site running version 6.1.1, exact same theme & cloned database.

Within the theme, there are numerous places that use the `get_blog_details()` and `switch_to_blog()` WordPress functions to retrieve information about [mostly] the parent site.

This works fine in 6.0.3, but on the dev site with 6.1.1 I am ***sometimes**** getting an Error 500. I have nailed this error down to the usage of either of those functions. Prior to 6.1.1 update, the dev site was also running fine on 6.0.3, so this WordPress update has seemingly broken things.

*I say *sometimes* getting this error because;

- If I set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`, everything works, albeit with some PHP notices. No warning's, fatal's, nothing. All OK
- On some of the 'child' sites, everything works regardless. On some others, it doesn't. Either way, adding `WP_DEBUG` makes it work across all sites (as above).

If I set `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` I still get nothing. White screen, error 500, no errors, no messages.

I'm running out of ideas on this one, any help at all? I don't like the idea of enabling `WP_DEBUG` to 'fix' this, not to mention having to clear up all the notices.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Have you looked in your webserver logs? Usually there's a file named `error_log` somewhere in your Wordpress directory, or look where your server logs are written, such as `/var/log/apache2`

Comment: @aynber sorry, I should have included it: `PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 2153`. This is the error in the logs when I hit the error 500

Comment: It's maxing out the memory at 256M. You can throw more memory at it, or try to figure out why it needs more than 256M

Comment: @aynber Increased to 512M, same result. Literally `get_blog_details(1)` or `switch_to_blog(1`) causes this. `1` is valid as that is the primary `blog_id` within `_blogs` table. I've tried other blog ID's, same result

Comment: Update on what I wrote above: `get_blog_details(1)` returns expected if I place this anywhere in `functions.php`, but as soon as I run this in `header.php`, or `index.php`, or anywhere _after_ `functions.php`, it errors..

Comment: Do you have chance to check the logs and paste the exact error?

Comment: @MarcelloPerri Exact error in my comment above (PHP out of memory): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75628120/wordpress-multisite-gets-error-500-with-get-blog-details-or-switch-to-blog?noredirect=1#comment133424287_75628120